# savepoint and rollback commands not working in sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Using `Savepoint SQL` command in Android:

```
 final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try{

        String savePointStr = "SAVEPOINT latestFilterConfig";
       db.execSQL(savePointStr);

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        db.endTransaction();

    }
```

Using `Rollback` command:

```
final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        try{
           db.beginTransaction();

            String rollbackStr = ";rollback to savepoint latestFilterConfig";
            db.execSQL(rollbackStr);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

While executing my rollback command, it results in the following exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such savepoint: latestFilterConfig (code 1)
```

Please help me on this. I need to rollback to the save point.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html) says:

> The COMMIT command commits all outstanding transactions and leaves the transaction stack empty.

Savepoints and 'real' transactions must be properly nested.